# How to Filter specific values against specific words from text file and store it in list?

Tags: python, filtering

Like i have a text file abc.txt and it is like this

```
we 2 rt 3 re 3 tr vh kn mo
we 3 rt 5 re 5 tr yh kn me
we 4 rt 6 re 33 tr ph kn m3
we 5 rt 9 re 34 tr oh kn me
we 6 rt 8 re 32 tr kh kn md
```

now i want the values against the tr and after filtering it should get this result

```
[vh,yh,ph,oh,kh]
```

can anyone tell how to do it.what code should be write for it

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = [line.split()[7] for line in myfile]
```

should work if it's always the 8th column.

If the position of `tr` is variable, you could do

```
mylist = []
for line in myfile:
    items = line.split()
    mylist.append(items[items.index("tr")+1])
```

Comment: even better `line.split(' tr ')[1].split()[0]`.

Comment: @junjanes: Very clever! You should post this as an answer.

Comment: I'll leave it to you since your answer was the trigger :)

Comment: @junjanes: If a mediocre solution inspires a clever solution, credit should go to the author of the clever one.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler `line.split(' tr ')` is a list. `line.split(' tr ')[1]` is a string.

Comment: @junjanes ahhh, you're right. Well, ignore the previous comment :) I thought you had `line.split(' tr ').split()[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can split the lines as *before* `tr` and *after* `tr` and obtain the first word in the second part.

```
[ line.split(' tr ')[1].split()[0] for line in file ]
```

If there is more than one `tr`, the expression collects the word after the first one. Alternatively, this one collects the words after the last `tr` in a line:

```
[ line.split(' tr ')[-1].split()[0] for line in file ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not quite clear.  Does this what you are after?

```
[line.split()[7] for line in open("abc.txt")]
```

It returns the eighth "word" from every line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, something like this should do the job (not tested):

```
resultArray = []
for aString in yourFile:
    anArray = aString.split()
    for i in range(0, len(anArray) - 1):  //-1 in case tr is at the end of array
        if anArray[i] == 'tr':
            resultArray.append(anArray[i + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter

# tr value is in the 8th column
tr = itemgetter(7)

print map(tr, (line.split() for line in myfile.readlines()))
```

Answer (score 0):

One may try the following:

```
def filter_words(filename, magic_word):
    with open(filename) as f:
        all_words = f.read().strip().split()
        filtered_words = []
        i = 0
        while True:
            try:
                i = all_words.index(magic_word, i) + 1
                filtered_words.append(all_words[i])
            except IndexError, ValueError:
                break
        return filtered_words
```

This algorithm does not fail in case 'tr' happens to be the last word in the provided text file.

Example:

```
>>> filter_words('abc.txt', 'tr')
['vh', 'yh', 'ph', 'oh', 'kh']
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be simpler to use a regex ?

If 'we' , 'rt' , 're' , 'tr' are really constant at their places :

```
import re

ch = '''
we 2 rt 3 re 3 tr vh kn mo
we 3 rt 5 re 5 tr yh kn me
we 4 rt 6 re 33 tr ph kn m3
we 5 rt 9 re 34 tr oh kn me
we 6 rt 8 re 32 tr kh kn md'''

print re.findall('(?<= tr )([^ ]+)',ch)
```

If not, and then the position being the criterium to determine what to catch:

```
import re

ch = '''
we 2 rt 3 re 3 tr vh kn mo
we 3 rt 5 re 5 tr yh kn me
we 4 rt 6 re 33 tr ph kn m3
we 5 rt 9 re 34 tr oh kn me
we 6 rt 8 re 32 tr kh kn md'''

print [ mat.group(1)
        for mat in re.finditer('^(?:\w+ \d+ ){3}\w+ ([^ ]+) .+',ch,re.M)]
```