# How to Filter specific values against specific words from text file and store it in list?

Tags: python, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Filter specific values against specific words from text file and store it in list ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340953/how-to-filter-specific-values-against-specific-words-from-text-file-and-store-it)

I have a text file abc.txt and it is like this:

```
we 2 rt 3 re 3 tr vh kn mo
we 3 rt 5 re 5 tr yh kn me
we 4 rt 6 re 33 tr ph kn m3
we 5 rt 9 re 34 tr oh kn me
we 6 rt 8 re 32 tr kh kn md
```

I want the values against the tr and after filtering it should get this result:

```
[vh,yh,ph,oh,kh]
```

can anyone tell how to do it? What code should be write for it?

Comment: Will the data contain always the same fields? You could parse it with awk without problem if that is the case.

Comment: @larsmans: yes, definitely. Without my edits it is identical. This one is more recent.

Comment: @Benjamin: I'm sorry, but that's no excuse for the OP's triple posting of this question. It should be closed.

Answer (score 4):

```
words = []
f = open('abc.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    if 'tr' in line:
        linewords = line.split()
        ind = linewords.index('tr')
        words.append(linewords[ind + 1])
```

Also, if you're certain that the data is well formed, you can use awk:

```
awk '/tr/ {print $8}' abc.txt
```